# На какие объекты, кроме папок и файлов, можно поставить разрешения в Windows?

Tags: windows

На какие объекты, кроме папок и файлов, можно поставить разрешения в Windows?

Comment: [Службы управления правами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Службы_управления_правами). Не?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ можно найти из описания функции `SetSecurityInfo`.  Конкретно это:

- `SE_FILE_OBJECT` - файл или папка,
- `SE_SERVICE` - сервис Windows,
- `SE_PRINTER` - принтер,
- `SE_REGISTRY_KEY` и `SE_REGISTRY_WOW64_32KEY` - ключ реестра,
- `SE_LMSHARE` - network share (не знаю как по русски - сетевой ресурс?),
- `SE_KERNEL_OBJECT` - объект ядра, то есть событие, мьютекс, процесс, сокет, таймер, и так далее, много их,
- `SE_WINDOW_OBJECT` - десктоп,
- `SE_DS_OBJECT` и `SE_DS_OBJECT_ALL` - объект directory service в формате X.500
- `SE_PROVIDER_DEFINED_OBJECT` - это, вероятно, объект, определенный каким-нибудь драйвером,
- `SE_WMIGUID_OBJECT` - объект WMI.